# Creating dynamic QR Code with your own domain?

Tags: http, qr-code, barcode

I am currently in the process of creating a dynamic QR code.

The static image will point to an endpoint on my server
which then redirects the user to what ever page is needed.

How can I make the other protocols such as **smsto:3015555555** or **tel:5555555555**
work when a user is pointed to my page?

I have tried sending raw text in the headers and also in the body(i knew this wouldn't work)

Answer (score 1):

Just encode a short URL into the QR code and turn that into an appropriate [HTTP status 303](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) redirect on the server.

For example this one here goes to https://redirect.example.com/xyz

[image: This goes to https://redirect.example.com/xyz]

The server handling redirect.example.com would then be configured to produce the right 303 for the redirection.

---

EDIT, since I misunderstood the question: How about pushing the redirect link as a HTML meta redirect, i.e. something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=tel:…">
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct, this is what I'm doing. The issue isn't redirecting users to any other page. It comes when trying to doing some native actions like using the tel or smsto links

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for. I notice it works with smsto and tel but how can something like this work with those protocols not supported directly with the browser such as wifi connectivity or opening pdfs directly like some QR generators provide?

Comment: Ever URL scheme supported by the underlying OS, including custom URL schemes should work (after all, that how websites like Google Play, the Apple App Store, etc. are redirecting from the browser to the device app).

Comment: So in the example of WIFI:T:WPA;MYNETWORK;MYPASSWORD;H:;
which when scanned should ask the user to automatically connect to the wifi network, should work but it doesn't? Original question was answered so thanks i'll accept now i'm just wondering why these protocols don't work

Comment: @Mike, well, if "WIFI" is a registered protocol to the OS. Which however, after a quick search through the docs, isn't. –– Truth to be told, I'm pretty much certain, that any URL scheme that did allow for WiFi configuration would be a major security risk (akin to do the same thing as AP highjacking) and so probably no properly designed OS out there will accept WiFi or other network configuration through a resource received through a network.

Comment: @Mike: Truth to be told, I'm smelling an XY problem here. What exactly is the rationale that you want to push dynamic WiFi configuration to your users in the first place?

Comment: Correct, i was using the wifi protocol as an example because i know that sms and tel would work on all devices. I know that the Wifi scheme isn't available across all browsers and devices. You can put a SMS or tel link in a html tag and it'll work but no wifi or the other uri types that QR code supports

Comment: Also, i wasn't saying that it was a registered protocol for the OS, but if you check almost any QR Code generator some have shareable WIFI access as an option. If you scan the code you'll quickly see that the OS (in my case iOS) will instantly ask you to join the network.